# Where is the "CREATE TABLE" definition for catalog_product_flat* tables?

Tags: model, reindex

I'm looking to add indexes the table to it to make lookups faster. If you manually add an index in MySQL, it will disappear at the next Magento "reindexing" event.

Answer (score 6):

This happens here `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer::prepareFlatTable`

The table is built with magentos DDL `$table = $adapter->newTable($tableName);`

```
$table->addColumn(...);
$table->addIndex(...);
$table->addForeignKey();
$table->setComment("Catalog Product Flat (Store {$storeId})");
$adapter->createTable($table);
```

---

And if you are looking for a nice event, I think `catalog_product_flat_rebuild` should do

```
//\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer::updateEventAttributes
public function updateEventAttributes($storeId = null)
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_flat_rebuild', array(
        'store_id' => $storeId,
        'table'    => $this->getFlatTableName($storeId)
    ));
}
```

This method is called in

```
public function rebuild($store = null)
{
    // ...
    $this->prepareFlatTable($storeId);
    $this->cleanNonWebsiteProducts($storeId);
    $this->updateStaticAttributes($storeId);
    $this->updateEavAttributes($storeId);
    $this->updateEventAttributes($storeId);
    // ...
```

But I only read code, so please test, whether this works as expected :-)

Comment: What do you think about copying this file to the local folder and editing `public function getFlatIndexes` and adding my own `$this->_indexes['IDX_MYCOLUMN'] = array('type'=>'unique','fields'=>array('my_column'))`?

Comment: I prefer always events, because with the next magento update (and if something was changed) you burn in hell with this approach :-)